# How can we check any Email Id is deliverable or not ( exist or not in real ) through program?

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a huge list of email ids and I have to filter out all valid email ids , valid means really exist or not .

I am trying to implement `smtplib` for this but I am not sure about the right way. It gives random result for same email id, which is not exist (I have checked manually ) but it's showing sometimes exist and sometimes does not exit.

Is there any better or working method available ?

```
import socket
import smtplib
import dns.resolver

def get_connection_handler():
    try:
        # Get local server hostname
        # host = socket.gethostname()
        host = socket.getfqdn()
        username = 'myemilid@gmail.com' #used with working email_id
        password = 'password' #password

        # SMTP lib setup (use debug level for full output)
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587, timeout=30)
        server.set_debuglevel(1)

        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)
        return host, server
    except Exception as e:
        return None, None


def validate_email_id(server, host, email_list):

    for each_email_id in email_list:
        records = dns.resolver.query(each_email_id.split('@')[-1], 'MX')
        mxRecord = records[0].exchange
        mxRecord = str(mxRecord)

        # SMTP Conversation
        server.connect(mxRecord)
        server.helo(host)

        server.mail('myemailid@gmail.com')
        addressToVerify = 'ramanzzzzzooo@somedomain.com'
        code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))


email_list = ['email_id1@somedomain1.com','email_id1@somedomain2.com','email_id1@somedomain5.com','email_id1@somedomain4.com','email_id1@somedomain3.com',]


server,host = get_connection_handler()
validate_email_id(server,host,email_list)
```

It gives random result for same `email_id`, sometimes exist and sometimes does not.
Is there any other better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The [validate email](https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/) python package could help you in this situation. According to the documentation, it is used to check whether an email is "valid, properly formatted and really exists."

After installing using `pip install validate_email`, you could use it like this:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com')
```

Which returns `true` if the email is valid, `false` if not.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if syntax is correct, just lookup the RFC, read it and run! The only sane check is really anything@anything.anything. So vaildate with a package like @Nick Predey suggested or only check for @ and ..

The second part of your question is interesting. There is no method anymore to check if the e-mailaddress actually exists. In the early days there was finger to test if a user existed on a host. Nowadays that protocol isn't used anymore in the fight against spam (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_protocol)